# I receive "INFO @wi_cf80211_attach : Registered CFG8021 phy" on start up. What does it mean?

Tags: 14.04, boot, startup

When I boot up my laptop (Dell inspiron 1545) I receive this after grub menu:

```
[ 14.180431] INFO @wi_cf80211_attach : Registered CFG8021 phy
```

Any idea? It doesn't affect anything just would save my about 10 seconds of boot time.

Laptop specs are:

- Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4300 @ 2.10GHz × 2
- Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2
- 4 GB ram (32 bit os)